# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object (My case is different than all duplicates)

Tags: php, database

I 'm trying to update certain fields in a certain row in my data base which is defined by email but I get this error no matter what I do :

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line 63

this is the PHP code I use to do it :

```
<?php
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 'On' );
class DB_Functions {
    private $conn;
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new Db_Connect ();
    $this->conn = $db->connect ();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $latitude, $longitude, $userType) {
    $uuid = uniqid ( '', true );
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA ( $password );
    $encrypted_password = $hash ["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash ["salt"]; // salt

    $service = "none";
    $rate = "none";
    $rated_clients = "none";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, latitude, longitude, userType, salt, service, rate, rated_clients, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())" );
    $stmt->bind_param ( "sssssssssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $latitude, $longitude, $userType, $salt, $service, $rate, $rated_clients );
    $result = $stmt->execute ();
    $stmt->close ();
    var_dump ( $result );
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?" );

        $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $email );

        $stmt->execute ();
        $user = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
        $stmt->close ();
        var_dump ( $user );
        echo '</pre>';

        return $user;
    } else {

        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Storing data
 * returns data details
 */
public function storeData($email, $service, $rate, $rated_clients) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "UPDATE users SET service = ? , rate = ? , rated_clients = ? WHERE email = ? " );
    $stmt->bind_param ( 'ssss', $service, $rate, $rated_clients, $email );
    var_dump ( $stmt->execute () );

    if ($stmt->execute ()) {
        $data = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
        $stmt->close ();
        echo '</pre>';
        var_dump ( $data );
        return $data;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?" );

    $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $email );

    if ($stmt->execute ()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
        $stmt->close ();
        $salt = $user ["salt"];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA ( $salt, $password );
        if ($hash == $user ["encrypted_password"]) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?" );

    $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $email );

    $stmt->execute ();

    $stmt->store_result ();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user existed
        $stmt->close ();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        $stmt->close ();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 *
 * @param
 *          password
 *          returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {
    $salt = sha1 ( rand () );
    $salt = substr ( $salt, 0, 10 );
    $encrypted = base64_encode ( sha1 ( $password . $salt, true ) . $salt );
    $hash = array (
            "salt" => $salt,
            "encrypted" => $encrypted 
    );
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 *
 * @param
 *          salt, password
 *          returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {
    $hash = base64_encode ( sha1 ( $password . $salt, true ) . $salt );

    return $hash;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "UPDATE users SET service = ? , SET rate = ? , SET rated_clients = ? WHERE email = ? " );
```

To be:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "UPDATE users SET service = ? , rate = ? , rated_clients = ? WHERE email = ? " );
```

Comment: excellent now i get this :( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line 67

Comment: Ok, I have to look at `DB_Functions.php`, I expect that you have an SQL syntax error

Comment: this line 67    $data = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();

Comment: You do not need this line at all, Because the operation is `UPDATE` not `SELECT`.
And if you want to retrieve the affected rows you can use `$stmt->affected_rows;`

Comment: @ wajeeh ok i did return $stmt ->affected_rows; but it returns something rather than an object ... what do you think did happen ?

Comment: `$stmt ->affected_rows` returns integer value not an object